# USB-C connector, plug detection and pull up for disconnect

Tags: usb

According to below circuit:

- is the USB_PLUG signal provided properly? I would like to have logical 1 when USB_VBUS is provided (5V) and 0 otherwise,
- is the 1k5 pull up resistor properly controlled? I would like to disconnect from host when any of SYS_NRST or USB_PULL is driven low.
- What kind of T1, T2 and T3 transistors should I use?

[image: USB-C connector, plug detection and pull up for disconnect]

Comment: Is it correct that your circuit will act as a *USB device* (as opposed to a *USB host*)? And your circuit is self-powered, i.e. it doesn't need any power from the USB bus, right?

Comment: Yes, it will act as a USB Device. But I'd like to use USB as powering optio (when no other source is provided)

Comment: You have no pull-down on USB_VBUS. There's no condition which will switch T3 on and pull USB_PLUG low.

Comment: Oh, you are right @brhans! Thank you so much! Would 4k7 be ok? Do you see any other issues?

Comment: The USB_DATP pull-down (disconnect) will only work when both SYS_NRST and USB_PULL are driven low. The MOSFETs should probably be in parallel instead of in series.

Comment: Many USB transceivers or USB peripherals within a MCU have the 1.5k pull-up resistor built-in and often even software controlled. Are you sure you need it in your case?